# Wordpress port redirect error

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect

I tried installing wordpress localy using WAMP - but it seems that some setup is wrong because when I try accesing the http://localhost:1550/wordpress it redirects me to http://localhost:8080/wordpress where I get an error - 404 ERROR!

I don't quite seem to undersand why does this problem seems to occur!

P.S. I've have made all the changes on the apache httpd.conf to listen to 1550 port!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress has configurations that store the site URL, which it uses to handle redirects. This is stored in the database in a table called wp_options. You'll need to update "siteurl" and "home" to change the port from :8080 to :1550.