# apache mod_rewrite .htaccess stale redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had my apache server port on 8080 and for wordpress page friendly url I setup .htaccess as below.

I had following .htaccess in my /var/www/html/wordpress dir.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now I have changed port to 80.  But the web browser is doing redirection to 8080 port and thus I am unable to serve the page from wordpress.

I have also tried below in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule (.*) http://${HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NE]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But browser still (after clearing cache) continues to go to port 8080.

The url using port 8080 was:

```
http://49.40.2.94:8080/wordpress/frequently-asked-questions/
```

After changing to port 80 it still it getting redirected to

```
http://49.40.2.94:8080/wordpress/frequently-asked-questions/
```

even if I type:

```
http://49.40.2.94/wordpress/frequently-asked-questions/
```

So the stale url without port 8080 I want to stop it since server no longer uses 8080.

Also after this in a day or so I need to start using FQDN for the IP.  will that change in urls affect the mod_rewrite rules ?

results after knowarth suggestion attempted: I cleared cache from browser but same results of redirect to 8080.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule (.*) http://${HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NE]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress



100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/productpage.py HTTP/1.1" 200 1941 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4204 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 345 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /images/jio-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5315 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /images/wifi-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1354 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 93113 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /images/offers-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 942 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /images/discover-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 858 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /images/android-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3447 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 198126 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:09 +0530] "GET /images/apple-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1475 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:10 +0530] "GET /images/landscape-bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 609231 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.28.145 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:33:17 +0530] "GET /wordpress/frequently-asked-questions/ HTTP/1.1" 301 - "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/productpage.py HTTP/1.1" 200 1703 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4204 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 345 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /images/jio-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5315 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /images/wifi-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1354 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 93113 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /images/offers-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 942 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /images/discover-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 858 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /images/android-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3447 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:27 +0530] "GET /js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 198126 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:28 +0530] "GET /images/portrait-bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 692885 "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:28 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 286 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
100.112.3.35 - - [13/Aug/2014:15:41:34 +0530] "GET /wordpress/frequently-asked-questions/ HTTP/1.1" 301 - "http://49.40.2.94/cgi-bin/productpage.py" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Micromax A116 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.131 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 2):

Put RewriteBase after "RewriteEngine On" value.

Comment: tried but does not seem to work.  please check whether i did the test as you thought.

Comment: I just checked your link, it seems to be working properly as expected. Can you post what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

it was wordpress issue.  The settings has siteurl and home setting which was using port 8080.

.[Wordpress port redirect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485345/wordpress-port-redirect-error) and this url helped resolve.